# EF doesn't pull foreign key when saving in controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've been kind of going in circles trying to get the id (foreign key) to pull from the foreign key table inside my controller method. I have tried a bunch of different methods and techniques but no luck. footer_image_det is the "child" table. I'm using a pk/fk combined but not sure if that is the best method or not. When I debug through the controller, the model isn't pulling the footer_image id, it's always 0. How do I get it to pull the correct id? I've added many images so the id is definitely not 0.

This is the error I get:
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_footer_image_dets_footer_images". The conflict occurred in database "rsqps", table "wst.footer_images", column 'id'.
The statement has been terminated.

Model 1:

```
  public partial class footer_images
  {
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string file_name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string content_type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public byte[] image { get; set; }

    public int? footer_id { get; set; }

    public virtual footer_image_dets footer_image_dets { get; set; }
}
```

Model 2:

```
  public partial class footer_image_dets
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string target_url { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("footer_images")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public virtual footer_images footer_images { get; set; }
}
```

Controller method:

```
    public IHttpActionResult Post(footer_image_dets footer_image_detail)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            db.footer_image_dets.Add(footer_image_detail);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }           
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = footer_image_detail.id }, footer_image_detail);           
    }
```

Comment: please show what do you send (real data in footer_image_detail)

Comment: I think that you are having issues with the 1 to 1 mapping here. I never use the attributes at all for that reason. Can you please share the exception message and some shots of the data you are sending?

Comment: @Miguel - I posted the exception above the code and yes that is my issue. I am using 1 controller method to post the image and another for the image details which is just a target_url but must be linked by foreign key to the actual image. I am using AngularJS for the front - end.

Comment: @Vecchiasignora - I am just sending the target_url and the id (foreign key) supposed to get updated. Like I just said to Miguel - 2 different methods and models here cause I am using AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You have `one-to-one` relation with `parent-child` (by `foreign key`) and so i think you should insert `child` model via `parent` model, try it

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(footer_image_dets footer_image_detail)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var parent = db.footer_images.Find(footer_image_detail.Id);
            if (parent != null) 
            {
              parent.footer_image_dets.Add(footer_image_detail);
              // it will work normally if you dont have child model(because  
              // your foreign key is key and there cant be inserted second  
              // row by same id, if you have child model you can update it,  
              // it depends on your logic do you want to have one-to-one 
              // reletion or no... )
              db.SaveChanges();
            }
            else 
            {
              //Create exception or yous specific logic here
            }
        }           
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = footer_image_detail.id }, footer_image_detail);           
    }
```